# What regression should I use to analyse these results and what conclusions can be drawn from the data?

Tags: regression

I have used a number of indicators to get an understanding of the environmental and economic sustainability of crop farms in England. The environmental and economic indicators have been combined to create an overarching economic and environmental indicator for each farm in a database of 237 farms. The indicators where then averaged across farms in each county (23 counties represented in the data) to get the average economic and environmental sustainability of farms in an area of England.

Agriculture is very complex with a significant number of interconnected variables impacting the condition on any given farm so I recognise that it is unrealistic to attempt to draw any relationship of causality from the results. The indicators used in this study were chosen specifically to be able to gather an understanding of sustainability for any farm in the UK as an initial high level baseline, potentially leading to further more detailed study. However, I would like to know what conclusions can be drawn about the relationship between environmental and economic sustainability based on these indicators. And, if any conclusions can be drawn, what sort of regression or analysis is most appropriate to lead to those conclusions?

I initially tried a simple linear trend line - there was a weak negative correlation with an R^2 of 0.28
Is this the correct statistical analysis approach? How can I improve my analysis to draw more confident results and correctly identify the relationship (if any) between the economic and environmental indicators?

[image: Data table]

[image: Environmental sustainability vs. economic sustainability]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach to the problem is not bad, but there are some ways you could get more information about the data, and maybe better results:

**1. I wouldn't get average environmental and economic scores per county, it can be a very bad idea:**

1.a. Average is a measurement of central tendency that gets the central point between the highest and lowest value you got on a certain distribution. Knowing that, given the most of cases you won't have symmetric distributions, average can be a very bad measurement of central tendency, and if you use it without a dispersion measurement (variance) you will be also sending a big part of the variability of your data to trash, so, doubly bad.

1.b. Variability of data (variance) is VERY IMPORTANT for modelling. If you use average scores per county, you will be "killing" that variability between farms, and with that, you will be losing a lot of richness of your data (...and the effort to gather that information too). **Generally**, more observations = more variance = better (more realistic/reliable) models.

1.c. **Solution proposed:** I would use scores PER FARM. Try to visualize your data with a scatterplot like the one you sent, but PER FARM (237 observations = 237 points), not by county (only 23 observations), and try to understand its morphology.

**2. How to know if there is some clustering of variance by county:** If you want (or need) to know the influence of counties, you could get that information performing a **linear mixed effects model** (LMM), using the variable "county" as a random effect variable. If your intraclass correlation (ICC) results different than zero, so a LMM it's the way. If you don't want or need that information or if the ICC is not different than zero, so you could go ahead with a classical linear model. If you finally determine to use a LMM, be careful with its interpretation as it can be a little tricky if you are not used to them.

**3. Check if you are able to perform a linear model with your data**: Have you checked if your data satisfy the statistical assumptions of a linear model (i.e: homoscedasticity, etc)? Having a look on your plot, I can advert that there is a high probability that you aren't accomplishing them.

**4. Try to better model your data after understanding the morphology of your scatterplot**: As you are comparing numeric variables, you can get a lot of visual information with the scatterplot for better modelling. Visually, a straight line doesn't fit well the variance of your dots, so probably there isn't a straight linear relationship between economic and environmental scores. Looking at your data, maybe there is an hyperbolic relationship (I'm just guessing here), so you could try with a quadratic term on your regression equation.

**Useful references:**

-de Rey, C. C. M. V., Galindo, M. G., & Velarde, M. A. (2001). Effects of using mean scores in regression models: an example from environmental psychology. Quality and Quantity, 35(2), 191-202.

-https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/the-intraclass-correlation-coefficient-in-mixed-models/#:~:text=The%20ICC%2C%20or%20Intraclass%20Correlation,of%20clustering%20in%20the%20data.

-http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html

-https://derek-corcoran-barrios.github.io/CursoMulti/_book/CriteriosInfo.html#modelos-explicativos-y-predictivos  (this is written in spanish but you can get a very good insight on adding quadratic terms to your regression)